# Axios Retry Infinite Loop

Tags: reactjs, axios, interceptor

I am using an Axios interceptor (in React) to retry on 401 (when my access token expires).  I want to limit to one retry but for some reason I'm unable to read the retried property I am defining.

This is the code I am using in the interceptor.

```
const responseIntercept = axios.interceptors.response.use(
  (response) => response,
  async (error) => {
    const prevRequest = error?.config;
    console.log(prevRequest);
    console.log(prevRequest.retried);
    if (error?.response?.status === 401 && !prevRequest?.retried) {
      await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 1500)); // only here to delay the infinite retries
      prevRequest.retried = true;
      // log here returns true
      const newAccessToken = await refresh();
      prevRequest.headers['Authorization'] = newAccessToken;
      return axios(prevRequest);
    }
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);
```

For some reason, logging of prevRequest shows an object with the property retried, but the second log of .retried always logs 'undefined'.  I assume this is the problem but I have no idea why I can see the property set but can't access it.

If I log prevRequest after adding the property, it does return true.

[console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2D21G.png)

Edit (solution): After taking bogdanoff's advice, this is the working solution I ended up with:

```
const NO_RETRY_HEADER = 'x-no-retry'
```

...

```
const responseIntercept = axiosPrivate.interceptors.response.use(
  (response) => response,
  async (error) => {
    var prevRequest = error?.config;
    if (error?.response?.status === 401 && prevRequest?.headers[NO_RETRY_HEADER] == null) {
      // get new token, return error if refresh errors
      try {
        const newAccessToken = await refresh(controller.signal);

        // retry with new token
        prevRequest.headers[NO_RETRY_HEADER] = 'true';
        prevRequest.headers['Authorization'] = newAccessToken;
        return axiosPrivate(prevRequest);

      } catch (error) {/* no-op */}
    }
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have been there recently, I used headers instead of modifying config.

```
const NO_RETRY_HEADER = 'x-no-retry'

const responseIntercept = axios.interceptors.response.use(undefined, async (error) => {
  if (!axios.isCancel(error) && axios.isAxiosError(error) && error.response.status === 401) {
    if (error.config.headers && error.config.headers[NO_RETRY_HEADER]) {
      return Promise.reject(error)
    }
    error.config.headers ||= {}
    error.config.headers[NO_RETRY_HEADER] = 'true' // string val only
    const newAccessToken = await refresh()
    error.config.headers['Authorization'] = newAccessToken
    return axios(error.config)
  }
  return Promise.reject(error)
})
```

Comment: Thanks.  I think there is an issue with Axios.  If I stringify and then parse the object, some of the fields drop (assuming malformed object).  As for your solution, I'm not seeing the header show up either.  Sigh.  I'll keep fighting with the header idea, thanks again :)

Comment: Got it using the header, thanks!

Comment: @GregT.Wallace I made slight mistake in last 2 lines while copy-pasting, it has been fixed check it out.

Comment: No problem, I got it working :)