# react js sending request in loop when an exception throw from backend

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have react js which intercepts response and check for jwt token expiry and issue refresh token

request interceptor..

```
customAxios.interceptors.request.use(async (config) => {
  const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('authUser'));
  console.log('request interceptor user ' + user);
  if (user?.productUserMO) {
    config.headers['X-TENANTID'] = `${user.productUserMO.customerId}`;
  }
  if (user && user.token) {
    config.headers["Authorization"] = `Bearer ${user.token}`;
  }
  return config;
});
```

response interceptor

```
customAxios.interceptors.response.use(
  undefined,
  error => {
    const errorConfig = error.config;
    const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('authUser'));
    console.log("url is" + errorConfig.url)
    if (user) {
      if (errorConfig.url !== Constants.LOGIN_URL) {
        if (error.response?.status === 401 && !errorConfig.retry) {
         
          errorConfig.retry = true;
          //get refresh token if token got expired else redirect to token expired page
          if (!refreshPromise) {
            const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('authUser'));
            UserService.refreshToken(user)
              .then(response => {  sot 
                localStorage.setItem('authUser', JSON.stringify(response.data));
                refreshPromise = response.data.refreshToken
                return customAxios(errorConfig);
              }).catch(e => {
                customAxios(errorConfig);
                 //exception occurs at this point and getting into loop
                localStorage.setItem('errorMsg', e.response.data.message);
                window.location.href = Constants.ERROR_PAGE;
                return Promise.reject(error);
              }).finally(
                clearPromise(errorConfig)
              );
          } else {   
              return customAxios(errorConfig);
          }
        } else if (errorConfig.retry) {
          return customAxios(errorConfig);
        } else {
         return Promise.reject(error);
        }
      } else {
        return Promise.reject(error);
      }
    } else {
      if (errorConfig.url !== Constants.LOGIN_URL) {
        localStorage.setItem('errorMsg', 'Unauthorized access');
        window.location.href = Constants.ERROR_PAGE;
        return Promise.reject(error);
      } else {
        return Promise.reject(error);
      }
    }
  }
);
```

when there is exception at backend, my page is keep sending request in loop and not exiting when there is error. issue happen when there is exception in catch block due to "e.response.data.message" is undefined. but i want to stop sending request incase of any exception inside catch block.

Comment: Have a look here it can help you stop the loop 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73363862/axios-retry-infinite-loop